# Viewing only the current month FullCalendar

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon friends, how do I display only the names of the events by the month, not the year as shown in the code below. Example, has 04 user in month 09.

```
<?php

//Database
$data = array();


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "agenda");

mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $obj->id,
            'title'=> $obj->title,
            'start'=> $obj->start
        );
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#clientes').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events : <?php echo json_encode($data);?>
        });

    });

</script>
```

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGUw8.png)

[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3u6I.png)

This is the code of the second block of the same result.

```
<?php

//Database
$data = array();

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "agenda");

mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');

$month = date('n');
$year = date('Y');
$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE MONTH(`start`) = $month AND YEAR(`start`) = $year";


if ($result = $link->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $obj->id,
            'title'=> $obj->title,
            'start'=> $obj->start
        );
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

[image]

If the code is so, he warns "Invalid Data":

```
$month = date('n');
$year = date('Y');
if (is_int($month) && is_int($year)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE MONTH(`start`) = $month AND YEAR(`start`) = $year";
} else {
    die ('Invalid data');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Problem Making Next make way.

Placing the select as follows.

```
$query = "select id, title,  concat_ws( '-', year(now()), MONTH(start), DAY(start)) AS start from clientes";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL to limit the rows returned like so:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE MONTH(`start`) = 4 AND YEAR(`start`) = 2016;
```

To code it to work with variables submitted from a form:

```
$month = filter_var($_POST['month'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$year = filter_var($_POST['year'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if (is_int($month) && is_int($year)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE MONTH(`start`) = $month AND YEAR(`start`) = $year";
} else {
    die ('Invalid data');
}
```

Never submit data that hasn't been escaped, validated or sanitized to the database.  In this case I used validation because it ensures only integers will be used in the query.  You may also use **prepared** statements.

*START is a reserved word in MySQL, which is why the **`** (backtick)s are required.*

To get the current month and year from the server and use it in your code:

```
$month = date('n');
$year = date('Y');
$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE MONTH(`start`) = $month AND YEAR(`start`) = $year";

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
```

Comment: I'm not getting , you can help me there in my own code would look like, please.

Comment: the same result @user2182349

Comment: Let's chat for this matter @user2182349 to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: I made the above example and gave " Invalid Date " and Notice: Undefined index: month in line 40 and Notice: Undefined index: year in 41

Comment: I put the code of the second block . From the same result. Enter this chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45535/fullcalendar

Comment: Use the code in the **third** block, place it right above the if statement in your code. Copy the three lines, the one that starts with $month until the one that starts with $query and paste them where you have $query in your code.  I am sorry, I don't have time to chat.

Comment: So help me , for I am unable to do edit my code right way please.